# Internet Secure Tokenized transaction decline

Tags: delphi-2010, credit-card

Hi I am getting following error while processing tokenized Credit Card transaction using Internet Secure from My Delphi 2010 application :

```
Invalid Signature or Application ID. Error code return was 1092
```

My XML Request is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <TranxRequest><GatewayID>90015</GatewayID> <Products>16.05::1::WB::Wellbridge Charge::   {TEST}</Products><xxxTransType>00</xxxTransType> 
<Token>3b155f4612810040</Token> <xxxApplicationID>TESTUSER</xxxApplicationID>    <TransactionSignature>3bPfS/t7zHgyQ4WeL65chzgAsOCDb+nRNepcR7gScBxxzhIwQwh15qLYpjZ5LGP5y/GAEJ    +2YrxEOcvVqNfqJw</TransactionSignature>
<xxxTransCtg>MOK</xxxTransCtg></TranxRequest>
```

If I process normal credit card transaction it works well but not tokenized trasaction. It happened just two days back. And the problem is only while I am testing it on test environment.

Kindly Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokenised Transaction finally worked after transaction ID reset by Internet Secure Team.